# Dropping all schemas with no tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to drop all databases with zero tables I was able to get the databases with tables using 
`SELECT table_schema, count(table_name) FROM information_schema.tables group by table_schema`
But how can I delete the dbs not in this list. I can't do it manually because there are more then 500 dbs there.

Comment: Why do you create all those schemas?

Comment: @jarlh Imported a dump.

Comment: Use this to create DROP commands: `SELECT 'drop database ' || schema_name
FROM information_schema.schemta
WHERE schema_name NOT IN
 ( SELECT schema_name 
   FROM information_schema.tables
 )`

Comment: Does MySQL support `DROP RESTRICT` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the method posted by @dnoeth in the comments with a slightly diffrent query to get the drop commands and then with some Notepad++ magic executed them to drop all empty databases

```
SELECT  concat('drop database ',schema_name) FROM information_schema.schemata 
WHERE schema_name NOT IN
(SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA FROM information_schema.tables)
```

Answer (score 2):

About to know schemas without tables, you can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.schemata S
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 'TABLE' from information_schema.tables T
     WHERE T.table_schema = S.schema_name)
```

Because in system table `SCHEMATA` you'll find all schemas of your server and in table `TABLES` you'll find all tables in all schemas

The upper query must be input on cursor, so you must use a prepared statement to execute your cursor, because your `DROP DATABASE` has a variable (your schema_table) and it can be ran only with a prepared statement

Comment: But how to go about dropping them.

Comment: @AbdullahSaleem: Ok, wait for a moment, I'll update my answer